# Compiling a bunch of stuff in the folder (java, on a mac)

Tags: java, class, compilation

two questions:

- how do i compile a .java file that
  isn't on my username (like something
  in documents or some other sub
  folder)
- if i have multiple .java files and i
  compile one that contains method that
  are contained in the others does the
  compiler compile those other files.

heres an example of the second question.

example1.java:

```
class example1
{ 
main () {
    example2.method () }
}
```

example2.java:

```
class example2 
{  
     method () 
}
```

When i compile example1.java will example2.java also be compiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java can find referenced files in two ways: from the source path or the class path.

The source path tells javac where to find .java source files. If it needs to compile them it will. It will put them in the designated output directory.

The class path tells javac where to find .class files for compiled Java classes. Java will use these to resolve external references (like example2).

So in your case, Java will use an existing example2 if it can find one in the class path. If it can't it will find one in the source path and compile it (it will also do this if the class file exists under certain circumstances too). If it can't find it in the source path, it's a compile error.

Comment: you can set the classpath with the -cp flag, then pass in the list of directories to search in, the syntax is similar to the colon delimited syntax for setting your system PATH variable

Comment: well i don't know how to do that eather so why don't you write an answer that makes everything explicit and i'll throw an upbote or two your way.